# How do I get a glow in fields on focus?

Tags: html, css, forms

I noticed some browsers make some fields glow when you select a form, Chrome makes them have a yellow glow for example. How do you make a field glow? I believe it's something you specify loosely on the code since different browsers do different colors. How does that work? Is there a simple way I could do it?

Comment: Retagged as this has nothing to do with PHP, everything to do with CSS :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [Check out the demo](http://jsbin.com/owaya4)

---

**CSS Used:**

```
input:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus{
 border:1px solid #fafafa;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #007eff;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
 box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
}
```

[You can also check out this page i had created similar effect](http://www.techelitez.com/contact)

**Note:**

The `box-shadow` is CSS3 property meaning it won't work in IE<8, however you can use something like [CSS3PIE to get the support even in IE](http://css3pie.com/) :)

Comment: In Chrome this demo gets an odd double glow border. In IE9 it messes with the margins, I guess since IE9 form elements doesn't already have a border. There are the two only browsers I tested in, and I'm not surprised such a small bit of CSS doesn't work too well.

Comment: The link above "check out this page" is pointing to an expired domain.